# Django next url to HTTPS (Nginx)

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have added a SSL certificate to my nginx application, everything works fine, but when django paginates for the next url it uses: **http://** not **https://** How can I change this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue: Under proxy_pass http://django; SET

```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Also need to set

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

in setting.py file.